# Form submission isn't working with eventlistener?

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I added an eventlistener in my FORMTYPE to adapte the form regarding to the user.
The form is indeed adapted and displayed like I intended, but when I submit the form I got the following error:

**FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getAuthor() on array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Site/BlogBundle/Form/ArticleType.php line 47**

I use indeed the getAuthor() fonction in my ArticleType to make sure the current user is the author of the article displayed by the form.

Here is my ArticleTYPE

```
class Article extends AbstractType
{

  // I PASS VARIABLE $userId FROM CONTROLLER THROUGH createForm()
  private $userId;
  public function __construct($userId)
  {
     $this->userId = $userId;
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->remove('ArticlePhrases')
            ->remove('articletags');

    $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc = function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // ADAPT THE FORM REGARDING CURRENT USER
        if($this->userId == $data->getAuthor()->getId()) // LINE 47
        {
            $form->add('statut')                     
        }
    };
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc);
  }
(...)
}
```

here is my controller (absract)

```
$userId= $this->getUser()->getId();
$form_article = $this->createForm(new ArticleType($userId), $articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the PRE_SET_DATA, the $event->getData() return the default object that is bind to the form.
On the PRE_SUBMIT event, the $event->getData() return the array of the submitted data.

You can add a "if" statement, for example :

```
if(is_array($data) && $data['author']==$this->userId){ $form->add('statut'); }
```

Comment: OK thanks SImon, is there a way to get the array $data. I mean actually my ArticleType is in a collection. also I am not sure what $data array is constructed.. something like $data['article'][1]['author'] but cannot retrieve it properly

Comment: moreover you say that $even->getData return the array of the submitted data but I do not submit any author. Author is information linked to the article, no submission of it by the user.

Comment: If you don't submit any author, do you really need PRE_SUBMIT event ? I mean if there is no author yet, you don't need the "status" field ?

Comment: I do not know... I mean I want user to be able to change article.statut only if the user is the author of the article... so only if $user = $author. (I want field statut or the article displayed only if $user = $author and in case of a malware user I guess I also have to check before information is submited into the DB. right?

Comment: Wait, you dont want to display the form for an existing article for anyone, right ? So maybe you should use 2 different FormType, a CreateArticleType and an EditArticleType and restrict access to this one to its author directly in the controller.

Comment: Would it be secure enough? I mean if a malware user tries to submit a post and change the statut of an article?